# What are the 2 wires in my switch box

Tags: wiring

I have a 3 switch box. I have some high hats in the front and back of the room and a box in the center of the ceiling.
2 of the switches control each set of high hats. Both are blk & wht. connections. The 3rd switch has to red wires. I assumed the red wires were controlling the ceiling fixture but there is none. Problem is in the attic I see NO wires running to the ceiling box. Where might those red wires be going? Am I safe to just cap them off and run a new set of wires off blk & wht in the box up to the ceiling fixture and install the fixture?

Comment: 1 - Please upload a picture showing all the switches & wires. Do not disconnect anything. Upload multiple pictures if you can't pull out the switches far enough to get everything in one picture. Also upload a picture showing the wires/cables as they enter the box.
2 - Are these *wires* or *cables*? Two red would imply individual wires. But could also (very strange, but could be) 2 red wires "extra" from 2 black/white/red cables. Big difference between those possibilities.

Comment: Can you post photos of the inside of the switch box please?

Comment: Could there be a second switch location or a 3 way that would account for the extra wires with the limited info provided.